# SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

Tags: mysql

I am writing in SQL and trying to update a new colunm "rankFeild" in table "seker_w_adress". The updating is just fine, but when I am trying to order the rows selected so the colunm will get the biggest value exist for this ID, I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Here is my code:

```
update seker_w_adress set rankFeild=si
from seker_w_adress as swa
join
(
select ID,gender,age,seker_ind as si  
from last_seker
)ls2
on swa.ID=ls2.ID and ((ls2.gender='female' and ls2.age<47) or (ls2.gender='male' and ls2.age<45))
order by ls2.si desc;
```

I tried to put "order by" into the ls2 brackets, like that:

```
update seker_w_adress set rankFeild=si
from seker_w_adress as swa
join
(
select ID,gender,age,seker_ind as si  
from last_seker
order by ls2.si desc
)ls2
on swa.ID=ls2.ID and ((ls2.gender='female' and ls2.age<47) or (ls2.gender='male' and ls2.age<45))
;
```

but it produces another error. What's the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your ORDER BY clause?

Comment: If you get this kind of errors, you should consult the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), and see that there is no `ORDER BY` that can be used in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: so why can't I use Order by into the ls2 select?

Comment: Are you sure that you use MySQL? it does not support `UPDATE .. SET .. FROM`.. maybe you use MS SQL aka SQL Server?

Comment: I am trying to update **rankFeild** to the biggest value **last_seker** table has to offer for this ID (it has more than one row for each ID)

Comment: *I am trying to update rankFeild to the biggest value last_seker* You must obtain this "biggest value" in the subquery with GROUP BY and MAX().

Comment: maybe... I just opened SQL management and created a query for the database

Comment: Execute `select @@version;` and show the output.

Comment: how exactly do I use group by and max?

Comment: Please provide: tables structures as code-formatted CREATE TABLE, some sample data as code-formatted INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table is enough) and desired final tables state with explanations.

Comment: This still isn't MySQL

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer - thanks to **Akina**:

```
update seker_w_adress set rankFeild=si
from seker_w_adress as swa
join
(
select ID,max(seker_ind) as si  
from last_seker
group by ID
)ls2
on swa.ID=ls2.ID 
join last_seker as ls
on ls.ID=ls2.ID and ((ls.gender='female' and ls.age<47) or (ls.gender='male' and ls.age<45));
```